# How to print data column wise in shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, sed, awk

I'm trying get some data using github API's and print in a csv file.
I'm get output something like below

```
4
3
2
1
user-1
user-2
user-3
user-4
```

I'm trying to achieve that the data should be displayed column-wise, something like this.

```
4    user-4
3    user-3
2    user-2
1    user-1
```

And the data will vary every time and I may need to add some more columns similar to this.

Please someone help to achieve this.

Comment: What are the "rules" for how the columns are to be assembled? for example, is the order of rows in the second column always to be reversed (`user-4` in row 1 and so on)?

Comment: I'm getting this output from jq, I achieved this using jq itself by parsing it as "jq -r '.[]|(.number|tostring)+" "+.user.login+" "+.created_at+" "+.merged_at'" @steeldriver

Comment: @harsha Could you provide a sample of the actual content?